# Making an Objective C Variable accessible outside method, while allowing method to still be called to update the values

Tags: objective-c

**Update:** From the accepted answer:

> As the name of this variable MyFirstVar is the same as the instance
>   declared in the class it **hides** the instance variable and you have two
>   distinct variables.

This made sense of quite a few things that were not obvious to me, so I'm just putting it at the top in case it's relevant to someone else.

---

**Original Post:**

Obviously this won't work:

```
@interface MyDelegate: NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
    {
        NSString * const MyFirstVar;
        NSString * const MySecondVar;
    }


-(void)setSomeVars;

@end

@implementation MyDelegate

    - (void)setSomeVars
    {
        NSString * const MyFirstVar = @"First Var";
        NSString * const MySecondVar = @"Second Var";
        NSLog(@"%@,%@",MyFirstVar,MySecondVar);  //  <--- This logs "First Var,Second Var" 
    }

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    [self setSomeVars];
    NSLog(@"%@,%@",MyFirstVar,MySecondVar);     //   <--- This logs "(null),(null)"

}

@end
```

See the two comment lines in bold.  What surprised me was that the code completion is perfectly happy to use these variables and using default set of warning/error rules, there are none.

If on the other hand I use:

```
    {
        __block NSString *MyFirstVar;
        __block NSString *MySecondVar;
    }
```

<del>And:</del>

```
    {
       MyFirstVar = @"First Var";
       MySecondVar = @"Second Var";
    }
```

...then it works as desired, and logs "First Var,Second Var", both inside **and** outside the `setSomeVars` method.

The objective for me here, as a learning exercise (I don't really want application wide variables), is to be able to reference the *most recent and up to date* value of the variables; anywhere, any time, and to be able to "update" those variables by calling `setSomeVars`

**The Question**:

How do I make these variables accessible from any block of code within the entire application **without** calling `setSomeVars` to evaluate them to the local scope?

Comment: FWIW, the technical terminology for this is "shadowing", not "hiding"

Comment: @jtbandes thanks for this.  Can I please ask for the purpose of a full understanding - xcode has separate warnings for `"Local declaration of 'myVar' hides instance variable"` and `"Declaration shadows a variable in the global scope"` - Does the term 'shadowing' apply to an *instance* variable itself or would it be more true to use this to refer to the redeclaration of a variable changing it's scope?

Comment: Both of those messages are enabled by the `-Wshadow` warning flag. They just describe slightly different situations (a global variable vs. an instance variable). Both situations involve shadowing.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing

Comment: Good on you @jtbandes - I was having a read of that article and appreciate the insight.

Comment: The terms "hiding" and "shadowing" are used to refer to a situation where one declaration in a scope closer to/the same as the point of reference prevents direct access to a declaration in a scope further out/away. While some make a distinction between the terms; e.g. using hiding when inheritance is involved (a declaration in a subclass hiding one in a superclass), and using shadowing in other cases (e.g. local/instance, local/global, inner local/outer local); others use the terms more flexibly/interchangeably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write:

```
NSString * const MyFirstVar = @"First Var";
```

inside of `setSomeVars` you are creating a new *local* variable, one which lasts until the call to `setSomeVars` finishes. As the name of this variable `MyFirstVar` is the same as the *instance* declared in the class it **hides** the instance variable and you have two distinct variables.

Simply change the statement to:

```
MyFirstVar = @"First Var";
```

and you have an access to the existing instance variable, no two variables, no hiding.

The qualifier `__block` is related to blocks and should not be used here.

Some other points:

- Declaring instance variables in the `@interface` is no longer recommended. Move the declarations and their enclosing braces, `{` & `}', to immediately follow the`@implementation`. This hides the variables from outside the class and therefore improves encapsulation which is good for program structure, correctness and maintenance.
- It is convention to start variable and method names with a lowercase letter, and class names with an uppercase letters. You used uppercase for your variables, and this is why the syntax colouring is wrong.

HTH

Comment: Thanks @CRD - still curious about the syntax colouring.  The capital variable names were actually an oversight in writing the example using copy/paste/autocorrect - I did actually change them back to `myFirstVar` and the code completion still shows the variables.  Shouldn't it really be telling me that the variables aren't referenced anywhere ? - Thanks